# Is it possible to capture the attribute of another element with an onclick event handler?

Tags: javascript, attributes, getattribute

The question's pretty self-explanatory.

Instead of capturing from itself like: `this.getAttribute('id'))` or `this.id`; is it possible to capture an attribute from another tag?

EDIT:

Sure, with an onclick:

Let's say:

```
<button onclick="Submit_Click("here I want to catch the attribute of another tag, not this one")">Save changes</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"? You can always locate other elements via `getElementById()`, `querySelector()`, etc.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use querySelector or getElementbyId like this:

```
<button onclick="Submit_Click(document.getElementById('id-of-other-element').getAttribute('id'));">Save changes</button>
```

Comment: This worked. It's a pretty straightforward solution and a simple one too. Thank you ver much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourElement.onclick = function() {
    var otherID = document.getElementById('youOtherElementId').id;
};
```